# Having evil thoughts

Tags: halal-haram, evil-thoughts

My question is, if someone has evil thoughts of shirk/kufr or doubts, does this make them a kufr? If they start to contemplate on them, or try to find a reason its not true, but they don’t actually believe in them or enjoy having these thoughts are they still a Muslim or will they be punished for it? Its hard to tell if it’s waswas or my own thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Allah SWT doesn’t punish you for your thoughts, if you act on these awful thoughts then that’s where you have went wrong. You can’t control your thoughts especially when you have waswas, so it’s recommended to let these thoughts pass your mind just don’t act upon them, thinking bad thoughts about God is one thing however acting upon it like stop praying, stop fasting or other then that’s where you have went wrong. So continue praying and worshipping Allah SWT and hope he brings ease to you.
Remember you are not punished for your thoughts just DO NOT act on them :) hope this helped

Also considering you argue with yourself and give reasons it’s untrue it’s most likely you are suffering from waswas this is because the shaytan is jealous and angry that you are getting closer to Allah SWT so don’t stop praying, make the shaytan angry and weak and soon it’ll die and your iman will be alive and strong!

Comment: You are right. But there is more you can add to make your ansewer better. Watch this Youtube video 14:30 min in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt-TGPmP3WY&t=863s

Answer (score 0):

Shaitain is known as the whisperer, because he whispers in the hearts of men and women. One should be on guard against evil thoughts as they originate from Shaitan. It's best to let these thoughts pass, or if they don't pass, to talk them over with a trusted friend or guide.